# How to simplify switch-case for Android images?

Tags: android, loops, switch-statement

Assuming that I have a long `switch(case)` block in Android where I define my images inside a loop:

```
    for(i=0;i<49;i++){
    switch(i)
    {

    case 0:
    imageFile.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img0);
    break;

    case 1:
    imageFile.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img1);
    break;

    (...)

    }}
```

Is there any other workaround to simplify it?

Comment: an array would look better. you could define the array in xml directly.

Comment: could you please explain how it apply to my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could just put it inside an `Array` as a static field of your class:

```
static int[] images = {R.drawable.img0,R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2...};
```

And then:

```
for(i=0;i<49;i++){
   imageFile.setBackgroundResource(images[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Wow this is such a better implementation

Comment: The important point here is to use the `static` reference in your `class`. This way you avoid unnecessary instances for your objects and get a free conscience for not wasting memory :) . Glad to  help!

Answer (score 1):

For me hashmap looks better in your case. i think.
In your case replace first item withe the number and the second with the resource.

```
HashMap map = new HashMap();
map.add( "cat", "Meow" );
map.add( "ape", "Squeak" );
map.add( "dog", "Woof" );
map.add( "bat", "Squeak" );
System.out.println( map );
System.out.println( "map.count( dog ) = " + map.count( "dog" ) );
HashMapIterator i = map.find( "dog" );
if ( i.equals( map.end() ) ) // A simpler way: if ( i.atEnd() ) ...
  System.out.println( "Could not find dog." );
else
  System.out.println( "Found " + i.get() );
System.out.println( "map.remove( dog ) = " + map.remove( "dog" ) );
HashMapIterator j = map.find( "dog" );
if ( j.atEnd() ) // A simpler way: if ( j.equals( map.end() ) ) ...
  System.out.println( "Could not find dog." );
else
  System.out.println( "Found " + j.get() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to define arrays in xml or in your code, you can use something like this

```
Resources res = getResources();
//assuming all your images name start with img
for(int i=0;i<49;i++){
    int id = res.getIdentifier("img" + i, "drawable", getPackageName());
    imageFile.setBackgroundResource(id);
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really lazy and not initialize an entire array this would work as well

**Note:**

> use of this function is discouraged. It is much more efficient to retrieve resources by identifier than by name.

[link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
for(i=0;i<49;i++){
   getResources().getIdentifier("img"+Integer.toString(i), "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the correct way:

```
private static final int[] IMAGES = new int[]{R.drawable.img0, R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2};
```

instead of a switch, do this:

```
 for(i=0;i<49;i++){   
    imageFile.setBackgroundResource(IMAGES[i]);
  }
```